# Pyspark- filter data from dataframe using list objects

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter

Hi I am looking for filter dataframe with data from list given and get output as list

```
data = [("emp_name","string"),("join_date","date"),("address","string"),("sal","bigint")]

schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("column_name",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("col_data_type",StringType(),True)
  ])
 
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
sparkDF.show()

+---------+----------+
|column_name|col_data_type|
+---------+----------+
|   emp_name| string|
|  join_date|   date|
|    address| string|
|        sal| bigint|
+---------+----------+
filter_col_list = ['bigint','date'] 

output_list = df.filter((col("col_data_type") in filter_col_list)).show()
```

but getting wrong output

expecting output_list  ['join_date','sal']

Comment: Try `col('col_data_type').isin(filter_col_list)`

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
df.filter(df.col_data_type.isin(filter_col_list)).show()
```